Can a Django management command tell when the server is running?
I have a management command that does some manipulation of the database so I don't want it running while the server is up. Is there a way to tell if the server is running from a management command

You could try to look if a process is listening to the port, although that can be another process.

No, a Django management command directly tell if the server is running on its own.

Django's management commands don't have builtin support for this, but you could always use ping:
import os
import platform

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.conf import settings


def host_is_up(host):
    if platform.system == 'Windows':
        flag = '-n'
    else:
        flag = '-c'

    command = f'ping {flag} 1 "{host}"'

    return os.system(command) == 0
    

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        for host in settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
            if 'localhost' in host or '127.0.0.1' in host:
                # ignore `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` regardless of port
                continue

            elif host_is_up(host):
                raise CommandError(f'The host: {host} is running')
        
        do_stuff()


Problem is, then I'd have to hard code the URL, which I don't want to do

@PeterKronenberg Well the IP has to be stored somewhere? You could pass it as a command argument, or you could check settings.py for the list of hosts.

@PeterKronenberg I added an example that checks each host in settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS
